# Delete request params URL Volley android

Tags: android, api, android-volley

I have an API with a delete function like this:

http://localhost/v1/deletePost/:id

when i try in postman succeed by entering param in url ":id" like ../deletePost/37".

[image]

how to implement the "/:id" request in android using Volley library?

Comment: You can simply concat id with the URL like
`String url = "http://localhost/v1/deletePost";`
`String id = "/"+3`
`String finalUrl =url+id;`

Comment: have you any sample code?

Comment: after I tried, his response issued a 400 error:

02-10 11: 16: 12.877 25325-25368 /? E / Volley: [4113] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://192.168.43.193/v1/deletePost/37 @UpendraShah

Comment: String DELETEADD = "http://192.168.43.193/v1/deletePost
String id = "/"+ id_post;
String finalUrl = DELETEADD + id;

Comment: please check my update questions, I added photos @UpendraShah

Comment: no, i have not figured out how to delete with method in url like that @AbhinavGupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) about how to use Volley Library

On the page Sending a Simple Request:

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
//...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, 
new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Then you need to change GET to DELETE `Request.Method.DELETE` and the url for your url with the id `http://localhost/v1/deletePost/37`

Will be something like this:

```
String baseUrl ="http://localhost/v1/deletePost/";
String url = baseUrl + "3" //Here you change the ID, can put as variable

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.DELETE, url, 
new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
```

Comment: I did not find it in the documentation

Comment: Well, i will try it @Canato